# Canvas качество изображения

Tags: canvas, html5

Здраствуйте! есть такая проблема
при выводе копии изображения в канве при помощи метода drawImage выведенная картинка сильно пикселится и выглядит очень некачественно кто знает как увеличить качество при выводе этим методом? исходная картинка очень качественная 2560 на 1600

Comment: Функция drawImage вызывается с масштабированием?

Comment: contxt.drawImage(image,10,10,280,130); вот так

Comment: У вас очень сильное и непропорциональное масштабирование идет, получается  2560x1600 преобразуется в 280x130, хотя для сохранения пропорций надо 280x175 и размеры уменьшаются в несколько раз. Это проблема растровых форматов графики. Как вариант можно перевести изображение в векторное SVG и подумать над пропорциями.

Comment: а другое решение какое то есть? все дело в том что исходный размер картинок в реальном скрипте не будет известен а выводимый размер должен бть одинаковый

Comment: а другое решение какое то есть? все дело в том что исходный размер картинок в реальном скрипте не будет известен а выводимый размер должен быть одинаковый 
ImageSmoothingEnabled тоже не работает  интересно в канве есть метод который выводит картинку без потери качества